# Listing and displaying WooCommerce Shipping Zones in the frontend?

Tags: php, shortcode, woocommerce-offtopic, array

I've been trying to create a simple shortcode function so I could display in the frontend of my website a list of available **Shipping Zones** along with their most reliable information such as the **zone name**, the **country or state**, the **method title**, **the cost**, as also all the **zip codes** attached to each shipping zone.

I’m able to retrieve all the shipping zones names by making a simple loop with the help of WooCommerce `get_zones()` function, but it returns an incredible confusing array of `stdClass objects`, so the other stuff I need to list are too deep within the array and that goes beyond my development skills.

Could anyone guide me on how to achieve that?

The function:

```
function shipping_zones_shortcode() {

    $delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

    foreach ( (array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone ) {
      echo ''.$the_zone['zone_name'].', ';

      print_r($delivery_zones);

    }
}

add_shortcode( 'list_shipping_zones', 'shipping_zones_shortcode', 10 );
```

I'm printing the `$delivery_zones` array just to get a clue of what it returns, an absolutely crazy multidimensional array, a trimmed e.g bellow:

---

Array ( [1] => Array ( [zone_id] => 1 [zone_name] => Betim - Centro [zone_order] => 0 [zone_locations] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => BR [type] => country ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [code] => BR:MG [type] => state ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-010 [type] => postcode ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-042 [type] => postcode ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-210 [type] => postcode ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-066 [type] => postcode ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-032 [type] => postcode ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-215 [type] => postcode ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-065 [type] => postcode ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-056 [type] => postcode ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 32600-055 [type] => postcode ) ) [meta_data] => Array ( ) [formatted_zone_location] => Brasil, Minas Gerais, 32600-010, 32600-042, 32600-210, 32600-066, 32600-032, 32600-215, 32600-065, 32600-056 e 104 outras regiões [shipping_methods] => Array ( [1] => WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate Object ( [fee_cost:protected] => [supports] => Array ( [0] => shipping-zones [1] => instance-settings [2] => instance-settings-modal ) [id] => flat_rate [method_title] => Taxa fixa [method_description] => Permite cobrar uma taxa fixa de entrega. [enabled] => yes [title] => Entrega em domicílio [rates] => Array ( ) [tax_status] => none [fee] => [minimum_fee] => [instance_id] => 1 [instance_form_fields] => Array ( [title] => Array ( [title] => Título do método [type] => text [description] => Isto controla o título que o usuário vê durante a finalização da compra. [default] => Taxa fixa [desc_tip] => 1 ) [tax_status] => Array ( [title] => Situação fiscal [type] => select [class] => wc-enhanced-select [default] => taxable [options] => Array ( [taxable] => Tributável [none] => Nenhum ) ) [cost] => Array ( [title] => Custo [type] => text [placeholder] => [description]...